# How to get all children of a node in tree structure ? SQL query?

Tags: sql, database, tree

table - user

columns - 
(userId ,name, managerId)

rows -

```
(1,nilesh,0)
(2,nikhil,1)    
(3,nitin ,2)  
(4,Ruchi,2)
```

if I give id of user it should list all reporting people to him .
if I give userId = 2 it should return 3,4.

Is this query correct

```
SELECT ad3.userId
FROM user au , user  au2 , user  au3
WHERE 
    ad.managerId = ad2.managerId AND 
    ad3.managerId = ad2.userId AND
    ad.userId=2
```

Is there any efficent way to manage tree structure in DB ?
How about right and left leaf way ?

Comment: What kind of database do you use?

Comment: If you are looking for alternative ways of implementing hierarchies in a relational database you can have a look at this presentation. http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

Comment: Very important to know the database engine. What you want is the "WITH" clause but its not universally supported.

Comment: "WITH" clause is called "recursive common table expression" and is supported by PostgreSQL, Firebird, Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase and H2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion, the problem with the adjacency list model is that it gets difficult to deal with in SQL especially when you don't know how deeply nested your tree structure is going to be.

The 'left and right leaf way' you mention is probably the nested set model and allows you to store things like this

```
LFT   RGT   Name
1     8      nilesh
2     7      nikhil
3     4      nitin
5     6      Ruchi
```

Then you can find all of anyones subordinates by simply

```
SELECT Name FROM Hierarchy WHERE LFT BETWEEN @LFT AND @RGT
```

I think it is much easier to deal with for querying but is harder to do for tree modifications.  If your data doesn't change much then I think this is a much better solution. (Not everyone will agree with me though)

There is a [Very good Tutorial here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: The adjancency model is very easy to deal with if the DBMS supports hierarchical queries (which nearly all major DBMS do nowadays)

Comment: @ David Steele dude you are great ! I was expecting this answer :)

Comment: Good point, I do need to look those up.  However I still think if the data doesn't change much NS is often the way to go as the queries for reading the data are so much easier to write and understand.

Comment: Thanks Nilesh.  Glad you like it.

Comment: Depending on the database you use, the adjacency list modal can be much faster.  See http://explainextended.com/2009/09/24/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-postgresql/.

Answer (score 14):

I use a text field to deal with trees in SQL. It's easier than using left/right values.

Lets take the example from the MySQL article:

```
+-----------------------+
| name                  |
+-----------------------+
| ELECTRONICS           |
|  TELEVISIONS          |
|   TUBE                |
|   LCD                 |
|   PLASMA              |
|  GAME CONSOLES        |
|  PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |
|   MP3 PLAYERS         |
|    FLASH              |
|   CD PLAYERS          |
|   2 WAY RADIOS        |
|    FRS                |
+-----------------------+
```

It would result in a table like this:

```
Id      ParentId        Lineage     Name

1       null            /1/         ELECTRONICS
2       1               /1/2/       TELEVISIONS
3       2               /1/2/3/     TUBE
4       2               /1/2/4/     LCD
5       2               /1/2/5/     PLASMA
6       6               /1/6/       GAME CONSOLES
7       1               /1/7/       PORTABLE ELECTRONICS
8       7               /1/7/8/     MP3 PLAYERS
9       8               /1/7/8/9/   FLASH
10      7               /1/7/10/    CD PLAYERS
11      1               /1/11/      2 WAY RADIOS
12      11              /1/11/12/   FRS
```

Do find all portables you simply use the Lineage from portables:

```
SELECT * FROM theTable WHERE Lineage LIKE '/1/7/%'
```

Cons:

- You need to do a UPDATE  after each INSERT to append PK to Lineage

Suggestion:

I usally add another column where I put the path as text in (for instance `'electronics/televisions/tube'`)

Comment: it deals with wild cards in sql which is not that much reliable .not efficient .IN case of deep tree this is a problem :) Wild card string search always hamper performance .

Comment: **a)** Not reliable? Exactly what is not reliable? **b)** I'm not saying that this is a generic solution working for all scenarios. How deep can your employee tree get? It's hardly a problem. **c)** I'm having a hard time to see how it can hamper performance in your case. Sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: dude you run query in SQL with wild card and with comparing numbers .Query for wild card will take more time .Hence more retrieval time for all children .First time I had taken approach like you but it is not that much efficient .

Comment: I am not saying that your approach is wrong I am saying that it is not that much efficient .;)

Comment: How many employees do you have? A couple of thousand at most? the difference will not be noticable. All I'm saying is that **all** code can refactored to be more effecient. Always use the most readable solution unless you can prove that your application will get a noticable difference in speed.

Comment: left leaf and right leaf concept is very simple to understand .if you read this with cool mind I am sure that you will support this solution . read - http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: I have not commented that at all, and I don't see how your comment is relevant to my answer? I wrote an answer since there are several approaches to the problem. All have their pros and cons.

Comment: amazing solution i know  performance, but there is simply no better way for me since i deal with existing table & works really fast on thousands of rows and use entity framwork

Comment: This is the best solution for querying trees in simple applications (mine was security clearance according to organizational charts) insert and update is not much complicated than nested sets but querying is even more convenient, performance can also be heavily boosted with an Index

Answer (score 12):

Something like this (ANSI SQL):

```
WITH RECURSIVE emptree (userid, name, managerid) AS (
    SELECT userid, 
           name, 
           managerid
    FROM the_table 
    WHERE userid = 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.userid, 
           c.name,
           c.managerid
    FROM the_table c
       JOIN emptree p ON p.userid = c.managerid
)
SELECT *
FROM emptree
```

Comment: David Steele answer is more efficient than yours! Nice try :)

Comment: But only if the tree doesn't change very often.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name is correct but if this really is for managers and staff then it is inlikely to change more than once a day.

Comment: @David Steele: absolutely. But it's always good to know all options ;)

Comment: you are correct .This model is good when there is frequent retrieval of nodes than update of node :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple answer to this question:

Table creation:

```
   Create Table #AllChilds(id int)
```

List item:

```
   Declare @ParentId int; 
   set @ParentId=(Select Id from Employee Where id=1)   
   -- Here put the id as the record for which you want all childs
   While(@ParentId is not null ) 
   begin 
   set @ParentId=(Select Id from Employee Where ParentId=@ParentId) 
   insert into #AllChilds values(@ParentId) 
   end
```

See the result:

```
   Select Id from #AllChilds
```

Cleanup:

```
Drop table #AllChilds
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT user.id FROM user WHERE user.managerid = 2
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Does not look as a tree structure.

Comment: no man it is tree structure here I give parent ID then I should get Id of all direct or indirect nodes .

Comment: if you give userid = 1 should it return 2, 3 ,4 or only 2 ?

Comment: @Nilesh – This query gives the exact output you asked for. If you want something else you need to update your question.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson I want more efficent thing than this .Imagine I have 10000 records .This query will take so much time .is there any other way ??

Comment: this query is perfect for that purpose))) if you need only 2 from userid = 1 )))

Comment: Guys please consider performance factor in case of million of records please suggest any change in table structure for faster retrieval of all children

Comment: if you need to build tree with all nodes and leafs the best way is to select all rows order it by parent_id and build it by means of your prog lang... but anyway if the table is huge it wont work very fast, cause it is impossible to hide an elephant into the box of matches)))