# PostgreSQL/Derby/Hibernate Insert Trigger - Retrieving inserted record, foreign key is always null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, triggers, derby

I've got tree structure entity named Category with children field.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id") 
@OrderColumn
@JsonProperty("children")
private List<Category> children = new LinkedList<Category>();
```

In database it looks like this:
[image: Category table]

I've got also lineage field helpful to list tree. (look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6277217) .

```
@JsonIgnore
@Column(name = "LINEAGE")
private String lineAge = new String("/");
```

After category creation i want append to that lineage parentId of inserted category. I created after insert trigger for that, but foreign key (PARENT_ID) of inserted row is always null in context of trigger.

```
create trigger add_category_lineage
  after insert on CATEGORY
  referencing new as insertedrow
  for each row 

update CATEGORY set LINEAGE = LINEAGE || TRIM(CAST((insertedrow.PARENT_ID AS CHAR(10)))) || '/'  where ID = insertedrow.ID and insertedrow.PARENT_ID is not null
```

I am using 10.11.1.1 derby. Why foreign key in inserted row (in trigger context only) is always null, it works for any other field for example name. Maybe instead of use after insert trigger to append parent id to lineage field can i do this from hibernate level ?

EDIT 1.

I tested this example with postgreSQL 9.4 and the result is the same.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION after_insert_category_trigger_function()
RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
    UPDATE category set lineage = lineage || new.parent_id::text || ''/''  where id = new.id;
    RETURN NEW;
END' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_category_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON category
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE after_insert_category_trigger_function();
```

The result after entity creation (id = 25). Like you can see it works well with name field (id = 23)  :

[image: Category table2]

It doesn't work with before insert trigger also:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION after_insert_category_trigger_function()
RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
    NEW.LINEAGE := NEW.LINEAGE || new.parent_id::text || ''/'';
  RETURN NEW;
END' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_category_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON category
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE after_insert_category_trigger_function();
```

Comment: Perhaps Hibernate is performing your insert operation as multiple separate SQL statements, and your trigger is running after some, but not all, of the SQL statements have been executed, and hence the data in the database is in a confusing state to you. Try enabling your Derby SQL log with -Dderby.logStatementText, and see if you can understand how your high-level operations are being performed at the SQL level by Hibernate.